# Standalone IPython notebook crashes on EDP's Canopy without network connection

Tags: ipython, enthought, jupyter-notebook, canopy

When I try to start the ipython notebook from EPD's Canopy while not connected to the Internet, the notebook crashes before starting up.
This does not happen when connected to the net.

Any help would be most welcome.

The short crash dump follows next. The full dump from setting `c.Application.verbose_crash=True` in the config file can be found here https://gist.github.com/xaverm/6873969

Short dump

```
~>.Canopy/EPDenvironment/bin/ipython notebook
[NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/xuserx/.ipython/profile_default'
[NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from /home/xuserx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".Canopy/EPDenvironment/bin/ipython", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(launch_new_instance())
  File "/home/xuserx/.Canopy/EPDenvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/ipapp.py", line 401, in launch_new_instance
    app.initialize()
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/home/xuserx/.Canopy/EPDenvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 84, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xuserx/.Canopy/EPDenvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/ipapp.py", line 313, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/home/xuserx/.Canopy/EPDenvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 84, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xuserx/.Canopy/EPDenvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 325, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/home/xuserx/.Canopy/EPDenvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/ipapp.py", line 308, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/home/xuserx/.Canopy/EPDenvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 84, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xuserx/.Canopy/EPDenvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 420, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/home/xuserx/.Canopy/EPDenvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 84, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xuserx/.Canopy/EPDenvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 359, in initialize_subcommand
    self.subapp.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/home/xuserx/.Canopy/EPDenvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 84, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xuserx/.Canopy/EPDenvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/html/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 532, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/home/xuserx/.Canopy/EPDenvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/html/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 450, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/home/xuserx/.Canopy/EPDenvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 100, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/home/xuserx/.Canopy/EPDenvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 248, in bind_sockets
    0, flags)):
gaierror: [Errno -9] Address family for hostname not supported
```

Comment: What version of IPython do you have? `ipython --version`?

Comment: Also, what version of Canopy, and how did you install it? Your install paths are quite non-standard, so I can't tell whether you are running the notebook from Canopy User Python as is required (https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538). Note that Canopy is completely separate from classic EPD. That said, there was a bug fixed in Canopy 1.1.1 for users behind a proxy who open local ipynb files.

Comment: @ThomasK the version is: 0.13.1 It has been installed from Enthought's site 2 days ago

Comment: @JonathanMarch see comment to ThomasK and Canopy's version is Version: 1.1.1.1452. Regarding proxies: I'm not behind one. Regarding if I'm running the 'proper' notebook, that's indeed something I'm not sure about - however - I've followed the instructions on http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/canopy-cli.html and set up an EPD environment with `~/.Canopy/canopy_cli -v setup ~/.Canopy/EPDenvironment`. After that my systems (linux) app starter had the path `.Canopy/EPDenvironment/bin/ipython` for ipython.

Comment: @JonathanMarch to continue: the error I am reporting refers to the ipython on the preceding path. Regarding the 'different' ipythons in Canopy. To me it seems there are three of them (i) `.Canopy/EPDenvironment/bin/ipython`, (ii) `.Canopy/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/ipython`, and (iii) `.Canopy/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/bin/ipython`. Now, all of them will start a notebook if connected to a network, however only (iii) will do if not and in that case (i) and (ii) produce the error reported here ... I don't understand this in view of the path written by Canopy into my app-starter.

Comment: @JonathanMarch finally and strangely enough ipython of type (iii) from the preceding behaves very similar to a standard ipython installation without Canopy/EPD and all that. E.g. on start up of the notebook if not connected to a network ipython (iii) will complain about a missing local MathJax - which is really confusing, since if I use the notebook not as a standalone notebook, but from within Canopy, then, the notebook will work with or without network connection, suggesting that Canopy does have a local MathJax installed. I.e. ipython (iii) is probably not to be invoked by the user.

Comment: I hope Canopy has a more up to date version of IPython than 0.13.1. It may well be a bug that's fixed in a newer version.

Comment: @ThomasK so this is starting to get beyond me: you are absolutely right about the 0.13.1, so therefore I checked the version output of all the three ipythons one finds in Canopy. Strange enough number (ii) and (iii) from my comment to JonathanMarch have version 1.1.0, however the one which gets generated by the `~/.Canopy/canopy_cli` command will show version 0.13.1. I also completely removed the EPD environment directory and regenerated it. However that ipython which resides in Canopy's EPD environment remains displaying version 0.13.1 ...

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be considerd **closed**: even after a complete Canopy reinstall & update, standalone ipython notebooks started from out of the directory generated by `~/Canopy/canopy_cli setup`, as described on http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/canopy-cli.html still do crash if the host is not connected to a network. However the ipython notebook started from `.Canopy/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/ipython` now works also if disconnected from a network. That's ok. for me.